# Struggling to code where you can input a file name like cat.jpg it will print image/jpg

Tags: python, cs50

So far I've tried `==` to check for exact match after
`sub_file_1, sub_file_2 = x.split(.)` since I need to remove everything before the "." but one of the AI inputs to check our code is `name.name.type` and it broke that question.

I've also tried `.replace("jpeg", "zxcz")` to replace it with a another random 4 letter sequence so the `elif ".jpg"` wouldn't connect those letters but none of the above has worked. I'm still in my first week and not really sure where to go next.

Please answer the question w/o giving me code explicitly or by citing the documentation of a function or possible solution.

```
# implement a program that prompts the user for the name of a file.
def main():
    file_type = input("File name: ")

    # convert to lowercase and strip white space.
    x = file_type.strip().lower()

    # then outputs that file’s media type if the file’s name ends,
    # in any of these suffixes .gif .jpg .jpeg .png .pdf .txt .zip
    if ".gif" in x:
        print("image/gif")
    elif ".jpg" in x:
        print("image/jpg")
    elif "jpeg" in x:
        print("image/jpeg")
    elif ".png" in x:
        print("image/png")
    elif ".pdf" in x:
        print("application/pdf")
    elif ".txt" in x:
        print("text/plain")
    elif ".zip" in x:
        print("application/zip")

    # if the file’s name ends with some other suffix or has no suffix at all,
    # output "application/octet-stream" instead.
    else:
        print("application/octet-stream")

main()
```

Comment: You can check what letters are at the end of a sting via its [`endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method. i.e. `if x.endswith("jpg"):`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the more customizable, readable and intuitive solution of your problem.**

```
def main():
    file_type = input("File name: ")
    
    # split it by '.' and for format take last part of it by slicing(-1)
    fmt = file_type.strip().lower().split('.')[-1]
    
    # define different class for future customisation
    image_format = ['gif','jpg','jpeg','png']
    text_format = ['txt']
    application_format = ['pdf','zip']
    
    if fmt in image_format:
        print("image/"+fmt)
    elif fmt in application_format:
        print("application/"+fmt)
    elif fmt in text_format:
        print("text/plain")
    else:
        print("application/octet-stream")
        
main()
```

If still have any doubts or suggestion, then comment below. **^**

Comment: Suggestion: The OP said "Please answer the question w/o giving me code explicitly".

Comment: so  i input this directly just to check against the ai answers and 2 of them flaged as red :( input of happy.jpg yields output of image/jpeg expected "image/jpeg", not "image/jpg\n"

:( input of happy.jpg yields output of image/jpeg
    expected "image/jpeg", not "image/jpg\n"

which is the same issue i was having before unfortunately

Comment: i figured it out, I needed both .jpg and .jpeg to output image/jpeg for the criteria sorry for the trouble but i really appreciate you taking the time to answer and also i get an example of a much more structured and cleaner code. sincely much appreciated